# expand.grid with existing chunks

Tags: r, permutation

Hi and good evening from germany :)

I'm pretty new to R, but I *really* am at my understanding limits.

Basicly I have n matrices, which are in a list. They look like this:

```
 $edu
   cue op split  pred
1  edu  <     1  TRUE
2  edu  >     1  TRUE
3  edu ==     1  TRUE
4  edu  <     2  TRUE
5  edu  >     2  TRUE
6  edu ==     2  TRUE
7  edu  <     3  TRUE
8  edu  >     3  TRUE
9  edu ==     3  TRUE

$religion
       cue op split  pred
1 religion ==     0  TRUE
2 religion ==     1  TRUE
3 religion ==     0 FALSE
4 religion ==     1 FALSE

$med_exp
       cue op split  pred
1 med_exp  ==     0  TRUE
2 med_exp  ==     1  TRUE
3 med_exp  ==     0 FALSE
4 med_exp  ==     1 FALSE
```

What I need, is something similar of what "expand.grid()" does. I need all items mixed together in all possible permutations (I checked 'combinat' package already), but in their original column-order (med_exp e.g. shouldn't have 'split's of more than 1 and only "==" as operator!).

I would be counterproductive, if I had the same "cuetest" (one line in one list) more than once in the table. I need the data preferably in a matrix, because I want to use "parRapply". Thats how the table should look like

```
   cue op split  pred      cue op split  pred     cue  op split  pred
   edu  <     1  TRUE religion ==     0  TRUE med_exp  ==     0  TRUE
   edu  <     1  TRUE religion ==     0  TRUE med_exp  ==     1  TRUE
   edu  <     1  TRUE religion ==     0  TRUE med_exp  ==     0  FALSE
   edu  <     1  TRUE religion ==     0  TRUE med_exp  ==     1  FALSE

    [..]
    med_exp  == 0 TRUE edu       <     1  TRUE religion ==     0  TRUE
```

Problem is, expand.grid mixes up even the sub-columns, and thats just giving me memory-trouble and is not necessary.

Here is the data to experiment with:

```
structure(list(edu = structure(list(cue = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "edu", class = "factor"), op = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("<", ">", "=="), class = "factor"), 
    split = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), pred = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("cue", "op", "split", 
"pred"), out.attrs = structure(list(dim = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), 
    dimnames = structure(list(Var1 = "Var1=edu", Var2 = c("Var2=<", 
    "Var2=>", "Var2==="), Var3 = c("Var3=1", "Var3=2", "Var3=3", 
    "Var3=4"), Var4 = c("Var4=TRUE", "Var4=FALSE")), .Names = c("Var1", 
    "Var2", "Var3", "Var4"))), .Names = c("dim", "dimnames")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L)), edu_hus = structure(list(cue = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "edu_hus", class = "factor"), op = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("<", ">", "=="), class = "factor"), 
    split = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), pred = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("cue", "op", "split", 
"pred"), out.attrs = structure(list(dim = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), 
    dimnames = structure(list(Var1 = "Var1=edu_hus", Var2 = c("Var2=<", 
    "Var2=>", "Var2==="), Var3 = c("Var3=1", "Var3=2", "Var3=3", 
    "Var3=4"), Var4 = c("Var4=TRUE", "Var4=FALSE")), .Names = c("Var1", 
    "Var2", "Var3", "Var4"))), .Names = c("dim", "dimnames")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L)), religion = structure(list(cue = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "religion", class = "factor"), op = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "==", class = "factor"), split = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L), pred = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("cue", 
"op", "split", "pred"), out.attrs = structure(list(dim = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), dimnames = structure(list(Var1 = "Var1=religion", 
    Var2 = "Var2===", Var3 = c("Var3=0", "Var3=1"), Var4 = c("Var4=TRUE", 
    "Var4=FALSE")), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4"
))), .Names = c("dim", "dimnames")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))), .Names = c("edu", "edu_hus", "religion"))
```

Thank you very much,
Marc

Comment: so what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear enough. I needed an "expand.grid" which doesn't tear apart the calculations I already had in a data frame, but recombines all rows of the DFs in all listelements. See answer from @Roland, which works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the data provided by `dput` is not the same as shown before. Also, the elements of the list are data.frames and not matrices. The former makes sense because you have a mix of different types (factors, integers, logicals) and a matrix can only hold one type. Thus the code I give here also returns a data.frame. You can always use `as.matrix` on it, but I advise against that for most purposes.

```
#create combinations of row indices
ind <- expand.grid(seq_len(nrow(dat[[3]])), 
                   seq_len(nrow(dat[[2]])), 
                   seq_len(nrow(dat[[1]])))

#use subsetting and cbind
res <- cbind(dat[[1]][ind[,3],],
              dat[[2]][ind[,2],], 
              dat[[3]][ind[,1],])

head(res)

#     cue op split pred     cue op split pred      cue op split  pred
# 1   edu  <     1 TRUE edu_hus  <     1 TRUE religion ==     0  TRUE
# 1.1 edu  <     1 TRUE edu_hus  <     1 TRUE religion ==     1  TRUE
# 1.2 edu  <     1 TRUE edu_hus  <     1 TRUE religion ==     0 FALSE
# 1.3 edu  <     1 TRUE edu_hus  <     1 TRUE religion ==     1 FALSE
# 1.4 edu  <     1 TRUE edu_hus  >     1 TRUE religion ==     0  TRUE
# 1.5 edu  <     1 TRUE edu_hus  >     1 TRUE religion ==     1  TRUE
```

If you have more columns, you can use `lapply` and `do.call` to generalize the approach:

```
sl <- lapply(dat, function(df) seq_len(nrow(df)))
sl <- sl[rev(seq_along(sl))]
ind <- do.call(expand.grid, sl)
ind <- ind[,rev(seq_along(dat))]

res <- do.call(cbind, lapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) dat[[i]][ind[,i],]))
```

Comment: Wow! This is amazing, and surprisingly fast! Thank you very much for your explanations. I don't get your whole code yet, but I work on that. Cheers and thank you!